# PHP directory warning and fatal error for require

Tags: php, html, require

> Warning: require(/user-settings/register.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\Project\Blog\register-page.php on line 4
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/user-settings/register.php' (include_path='D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\Project\Blog\register-page.php on line 4

I want to include connect.php and register.php in the file register-page.php, but I get an error. I am also using the connect.php file in the register.php file.

```
<?php 

require 'database-settings/connect.php';
require_once 'user-settings/register.php'; 

?>
```

[image]

Comment: I did not understand. I wanted to include the file with require and require_once

Comment: The error message doesn't match the code. It says the pathname is `/user-settings/register.php`, but the code doesn't have `/` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this `/user-settings/register.php` instead of `/user-settings/register.php` because you are not in the same folder with `user-settings` you are inside of it.